# Android: Refactoring XML files in Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, refactoring

Is there a way to easily rename XML files in Eclipse while developing for Android so that these changes are reflected in source code?

Right-clicking on the file in package view and selecting refactor->rename changes the file's name, but does not alter references to the file within the .java source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think such a thing exists for Android resources directory let alone layouts. You have to change the references manually.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old post, but i was trying to do the same and just came up with a solution to this in eclipse:

Search -> File Search -> Replace...

Replace:Current.Style.Name

With: New.Style.Name

Thats it! Nice and easy, i didn't want to deal with the hassle of going into all my xml layouts and changing them.